# Failing to install "igraph" package in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the 'igraph' package but running into this error:

```
** libs
gfortran   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c AMD/Source/amd.f -o AMD/Source/amd.o
clang: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=11.4'
make: *** [AMD/Source/amd.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘igraph’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/igraph’
```

Did some searches on the issue but haven't seen much coverage on this topic. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try `install.packages("igraph", type="binary")`. Do you really need to build from source? Usually that's not necessary.

Comment: It worked! Not sure what binary did but it just saved my life! I spent 8 hours yesterday trying to figure this out and you solved it with one argument! Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes it will ask you if you want to install from sources if a newer version is available that hasn't been compiled on CRAN yet. It seem the default is "yes" but that's rarely the best choice. Compiling packages can be messy and it's way easier to just use the precompiled binary.

Comment: I have the same problem but can't install from Binaries - no idea why. As usual with R, the the super useful error:

Error in install.packages("igraph", type = "binary") :
  type 'binary' is not supported on this platform